# Magento 2 Override two layout xml for a single module

Tags: magento2, layout

How to give 2 different layout xmls within a single module.
My module has one `routes.xml` with `route_id='catalogsearch'`

**My folder structure:**

```
Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index.php     //For CatalogSearch

Vendor\Module\Controller\Category\View.php     //For Catalog
```

So one of my overridden catalogsearch layout file is:

**catalogsearch_result_index.xml**

Now I want to override magento catalog module xml.
Magento maintains the route name for catalog as 'catalog' itself.

Now how should I create a separate layout file for my custom module.
Should it be: **`catalogsearch_category_view.xml`**?

If I had done like above, even if I search for keyword, in frontpage, I guess `toolbar.phtml` is calling, instead of catalog search.

My **catalogsearch_result_index.xml** (which seems to be fine):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::layer/view.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

**UPDATED:**   My **catalog_category_view.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list/toolbar.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

**routes.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="catalogsearch" frontName="catalogsearch">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**UPDATED:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your "catalogsearch_category_view.xm" file should be "catalog_category_view.xml".

I'm not sure if you need the routes.xml file. This file already exist in Magento_CatalogSearch module.

Your module should just inherit from magento's one.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Example_Module" setup_version="2.0.0" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: IN catalog_category_view.xml, will the name 'catalog' be taken from magento's ?   And are the contents of my catalog xml correct?

Comment: The content your file is correct. With catalog_category_view.xml you will override magento's category view. To modify the toolbar template i used :         <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" template="Example_Module::product/list/toolbar.phtml" />

Comment: I have updated the answer ..could you please check why i get like this

Comment: You have no css, are your css files in pub/static/frontend/... ?

Comment: Yes i have css in \Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\css\mycss.cs

Comment: Do you have clear the cache and deploy the css "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" (if pub/static dir is empty)

Comment: yes bro...i cleared cache, var generation, ran static deploy...

Comment: Maybe a permission issue ? or a die() / exit() in a file?